# parse entire website using python beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

When i try to parse https://www.forbes.com/ for learning purpose. when i run the code, it only parse one page, i mean, home page.

How can i parse entire website, i mean, all the page from a site.

My attempted codes are given below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

html_page = urlopen("http://www.bdjobs.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")




# To Export to csv file, we used below code.

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(links)
df.to_csv('link.csv')

#print(df)
```

Can you tell me please how can i parse entire websites, not one page?

Comment: You will need to crawl the site to get associated pages. Here's a site that describes using requests for a webcrawler: [simple web crawler / scraper tutorial using requests module in python](http://love-python.blogspot.com/2012/12/python-requests-simple-crawler-scraper.html)

Comment: wow! you want to scrape 1 Million page? https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aforbes.com

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of alternatives, it depends what you want to achieve.

**Write your own crawler**

Similarly as what you are trying to do in your code snippet, fetch a page from the website, identify all the interesting links in this page (using xpath, regular expressions, ...) and iterate until you have visited the whole domain.

This is probably most suitable for learning the basics of crawling, or to get some information quickly as a one-off task.

You'll have to be careful about a couple of thinks, like not to visit the same links twice, limit the domain(s) to avoid going to other websites etc.

**Use a web scraping framework**

If you are looking to perform some serious scraping, for a production application or some large scale scraping, consider using a framework such as [scrapy](https://scrapy.org).

It solves a lot of common problems for you, and it is a great way to learn advanced techniques of web scraping, by reading the documentation and diving into the code.